# activeadmin destroy batch action and pg_search rebuild

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, pg-search

I am working on a Rails web app. I have records in a model, called `AcademicPaper` that I deleted using the batch action destroy functionality that comes with `activeadmin`. Right after I did that, I noticed that there was an error of not found `ActiveRecord` for the `AcademicPaper` model in the controller method that utilized `pg_search` gem.

I realized that the `pg_search` was not synched with `ActiveRecord`s. Therefore, the solution was for me to run `PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(AcademicPaper)` in the rails console, which I did, which worked.

My question is: how can I avoid this error in a production environment and maybe rebuild the `pg_search` index every time an `active_admin` batch action occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from [Active Admin Documentation](https://activeadmin.info/9-batch-actions.html) -

> If you want, you can override the default batch action to do whatever you want:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  batch_action :destroy do |ids|
    super
    PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(AcademicPaper) 
  end
end
```

Comment: I accept your answer, but it would be great if I could do this in just one place to keep my code DRY. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This crashes with `NoMethodError: super called outside of method` when I try to run it.